# GitLab CE 15.7 / Docker registry with Self Signed Certificate.. not working

Tags: gitlab

I want to use the Gitlab Docker registry. I am using GitLab CE 15.7

I created my own CA and signed a certificate. GitLab UI and GitLab runners are working fine!

When it comes to the Docker Registry I have some issues. I configured the gitlab.rb like this:

```
 registry_external_url 'https://198.18.133.100:5000'
 registry['enable'] = true
 registry['username'] = "registry"
 registry['group'] = "registry"
 registry['registry_http_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:5000"
 registry['debug_addr'] = "localhost:5001"
 registry['env'] = {
   'SSL_CERT_DIR' => "/etc/gitlab/ssl/"
 }
 registry['rootcertbundle'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/198.18.133.100.crt"
```

Which also confuses me are the options for registry and registry_nginx.

I am not sure if I configured it correctly and the documentation doesn't help me a lot. I didn't spin up any docker container for the registry or anything. I believe that this comes in the binary of the GitLab (if I am not mistaken). I port 5000 is available and I can telnet.

However, while pushing the image to the registry I get the following error:

```
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get "https://198.18.133.100:5000/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

I tried already quite a lot of different configs and reconfigured the gitlab server.

Comment: You need to trust your own CA on the docker host. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90607 how to add your CA to the local trusted certificates.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, I solved it by adding the ca to /etc/docker/certs.d/<your-registry-host-name>

Comment: Now, I am getting another error:

$ docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
The push refers to repository [198.18.133.100/gitlab-instance-39123d19/ltrops-2977/ltrops-2977/dnac]
88fb8fa52c13: Preparing
6515074984c6: Preparing
error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning The resource that you are attempting to access does not exist or you don't have the necessary permissions to view it.</p>\n

Comment: Alright, but this looks like an standard HTTP 404 error, which occures bejond the TLS connection and therefore has nothing to do anymore with the issue described above. Read the error message: "The resource that you are attempting to access does not exist or you don't have the necessary permissions to view it." and use this an an entry point to start you investigations.

Comment: Hey, that was due to a wrong gitlab.rb config. I fixed it with:
registry_nginx['enable'] = true
registry_nginx['listen_https'] = true
registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
registry_external_url 'https://registry.YOUR_DOMAIN.gtld'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed with copying the ca at the following path:

```
mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/<your_registry_host_name>:<your_registry_host_port>
```

As well as the right config in the gitlab.rb

```
registry_nginx['enable'] = true
registry_nginx['listen_https'] = true
registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
registry_external_url 'https://registry.YOUR_DOMAIN.gtld'
```

Thanks all for your help!